# Change SVG <g/> Coordinates on Hover

Tags: javascript, svg

I have array of x and y coordinates:

```
var coordinateX = [10,20,30,40,50,....];
var coordinateY = [10,20,30,40,50,....]:
```

Those coordinates are circle centers in which I want to show tooltip when hover over circle.

```
for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].addEventListener('mousemove', show);
    circles[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}
```

Tooltip is represented as g element with rectangle and text inside it

```
<g id="poligon" visibility="hidden" class="element">
  <rect width="80" height="20" fill="white"/>
  <text class="tooltip" x="4" y="15" dominant-baseline="centered">Tooltip</text>
</g>

var poligon = svgDoc.getElementById("poligon")

function show(evt) {
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate(" + coordinateX[i] + ", " + coordinatey[i] + ")");
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
  textTooltipVrijednost.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "class");    
}

function hide(){
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
}
```

I tried to translate g element using `setAttribute` and changing x, y values of translate attribute, but I got only last position value. How to do this dynamically for each position?

Comment: What do you mean by last position value?

Comment: for example last value in coordinateX array is 50 and also last value in coordinateY array is 50....so with my code, when I hover over any circle my tooltip is shown on 50,50 position.

Comment: Ok the question is slightly different to what I thought it was, but here goes: where does the index `i` come from in `show(evt) {..coordinateX[i] + "," + coordinateY[i]`? If you are trying to make it so that it will move by the index upon which you originally created the event listener it will not work as the index `i` is not stored with the event listener. I encountered this self-same problem and solved it by using a Map structure between the relevant data with the physical DOM node in question

Comment: My idea was to loop trough coordinates arrays so I can pass each coordinate pair  (coordinateX[i] and coordinateY[i] to translate attribute of g element. And than call function show(evt) with event listener when hover belonging circle. Can you please explain me in more details what do you mean by using a Map structure between the relevant data with the physical DOM node in question?

Comment: A better idea would be using an outer div as tooltip.

Comment: @Zmaj if I'm honest I think I would listen to enxaneta's answer as they seem to understand your problem better than I can - I thought I saw a problem in your JavaScript code where you are trying to index your coordinate arrays with `i` (the variable you used to index `circles` that no longer exists), however that would create a reference error not the issue you described. I think I am wrong and you should listen to other people. Nonetheless `Map` in JS allows you to relate literally anything into pairs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to just pass `i` into your `show()` function.

```
for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {  // <-- change "var" to "let"
    circles[i].addEventListener('mousemove', function() { show(i) });
    circles[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}

function show(i) {
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "transform","translate(" + coordinateX[i] + ", " + coordinatey[i] + ")");
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
  textTooltipVrijednost.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "class");    
}
```

```js
var coordinateX = [10,20,30,40,50];
var coordinateY = [10,20,30,40,50];

var svgDoc = document.querySelector("svg");
var poligon = svgDoc.getElementById("poligon")

for (let i = 0; i < coordinateX.length; i++) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(svgDoc.namespaceURI, "circle");
  circle.setAttribute("cx", coordinateX[i]);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", coordinateY[i]);
  circle.setAttribute("r", "5");
  svgDoc.appendChild(circle);

  circle.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { show(i); } );
  circle.addEventListener('mouseout', hide);
}



function show(i) {
  poligon.setAttribute("transform","translate(" + coordinateX[i] + ", " + coordinateY[i] + ")");
  poligon.setAttribute("visibility", "visible");
}

function hide(){
  poligon.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200">

  <g id="poligon" visibility="hidden" class="element">
    <rect width="80" height="20" fill="white"/>
    <text class="tooltip" x="4" y="15" dominant-baseline="centered">Tooltip</text>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you both, I was straggling with this problem for some time.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented a better idea would be using an html element as a tooltip. This way you won't have problems when the at small sizes of the svg element when the text may become so small that you can't read it.

The main idea is to detect the position of the mouse over the svg element. If the mouse enter a circle the tooltip becomes visible and takes the position of the mouse. Also in this case is displaying the coords of the circle. When the mouse leaves the circle the tooltip's display goes back to `none`.

I hope it helps.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let coordinates = [{cx:10,cy:7,r:5},{cx:10,cy:30,r:5},{cx:50,cy:10,r:5},{cx:33,cy:25,r:5}]

let circles = []

coordinates.forEach(c=>{
  circles.push(drawCircle(c, svg))
})

circles.forEach((c,i)=>{
  c.addEventListener("mouseenter",(e)=>{
    let m = oMousePos(svg, e);
    let cx = coordinates[i].cx;
    let cy = coordinates[i].cy;
    tooltip.style.display = "block"
    tooltip.style.left = m.x+"px";
    tooltip.style.top = m.y+"px";
    tooltip.innerHTML = `${cx}, ${cy}`
  })
  c.addEventListener("mouseleave",(e)=>{
    tooltip.style.display = "none"
  })
})




function drawCircle(o, parent) {

  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}



function oMousePos(svg, evt) {
      var ClientRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
                return { //objeto
                x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
                y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
      }
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  width:100vh;
}
#wrap {
  position: relative;
}
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 60 40"></svg>

<div id="tooltip">0,0</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Useful, interesting answer